# Async/Await in reduce HOC function with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `async` `await` with `reduce` function in TypeScript:

```
const getMyItems = async (items: MyType[]) => {
  return await items.reduce(async (allItems, currItem) => {
    const shouldAddItem = await someCheck(currItem);
    return [...allItems, ...(shouldAddItem ? [currItem] : [])];
  }, []);
};
```

I get error on this line:

```
return await items.reduce(async (allItems, currItem) => {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Error message:

> ```
> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3,
> '(callbackfn: (previousValue: InviteASItemProps, currentValue:
> InviteASItemProps, currentIndex: number, array: InviteASItemProps[])
> => InviteASItemProps, initialValue: InviteASItemProps): InviteASItemProps', gave the following error.     Argument of type
> '(filteredItems: never[], currentItem: InviteASItemProps) =>
> Promise' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(previousValue: InviteASItemProps, currentValue:
> InviteASItemProps, currentIndex: number, array: InviteASItemProps[])
> => InviteASItemProps'.       Types of parameters 'filteredItems' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.         Type 'InviteASItemProps' is
> missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop,
> push, concat, and 29 more.   Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn:
> (previousValue: never[], currentValue: InviteASItemProps,
> currentIndex: number, array: InviteASItemProps[]) => never[],
> initialValue: never[]): never[]', gave the following error.
>     Argument of type '(filteredItems: never[], currentItem: InviteASItemProps) => Promise' is not
> assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: never[],
> currentValue: InviteASItemProps, currentIndex: number, array:
> InviteASItemProps[]) => never[]'.       Type
> 'Promise' is missing the following
> properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29
> more.
> ```

Any ideas why?

When I use `allItems: any` it's fixed.

Comment: This is because the initial value is an ordinary ```Array``` type, but it needs to be a ```Promise<Array>``` type. try replace ```[]``` with ```Promise.resolve([])```...

Comment: did that and added `await` before all uses of accumalator .. still same problem